# Selenium Chromedriver Headless mode problem, does not load an url

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, headless

Im a noob at programming I just started learning recently. I made a script to automate a process using selenium for python.The script logs in a webpage, scraps some info and downloads some pdf files some through wget others through requests because of the webpage structure and my limitations.

It works well but **if I run it on headless mode** it **fails** to download the file through wget. To get the url for this file I click on a href and then use the current_url method. **Here's where the problem seems to be** as I've printed the url and returns the previous url as if it hadn't clicked on the link therefore not loading the requiered page.

Might be important to point out that this href calls for a script(*I suppose*) to create the pdf and then redirects me to the actual url which is actually public. Heres the href:

"https://"WEBPAGE.COM"/admin.php?method=buildPDF&scode=JT9UM1FL5MP0P57UXFP6R5FT6LPE"

I did some research and tought it might be opening the pdf on another tab so I tried switching tabs to the same result.

Here's a sample of the code:

```
driver.get("https://webpage.com/")
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[text()='+variable+']//ancestor::td[1]//following::a[1]').click()
time.sleep(2)
pr=driver.current_url
print(pr)
url= pr
filename= variable + ".pdf" 
    
wget.download(url,'path')
```

All other "click()"s in the code work fine and I also tried increasing sleep up to 10 seconds but nothing works.

Any help/advise is really appreciated

Thanks

Comment: you can get HTML from selenium `driver.page_source` and save it in file to see what you get from server. Maybe server sends you different HTML then you expect. Maybe it sends some warning for bots.

Comment: Thanks for you repply, I did as you said but the source code seems to be exactly the same. I kept looking and if I got this right "https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1872" apparently headless chromedriver just doesn't support pdf viewing yet :(